# Why does accessing an array of pointers de-references the pointer of the pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, command-line-arguments

I cannot understand this unexpected C behavior where printing `argv[0]` prints `./a.out` instead of the actual content of `argv[0]` which should be a memory address because `argv` is an array of pointers.

If I create an array called `char name[] = "hello"` then I would expect to see `h` at `name[0]` and if `char * argv[]` holds, for example 3 pointers *(memory addresses)* then logically `argv[0]` should be a memory address.

My reasoning is that if I wanted to access the actual content of the memory address that `argv[0]` points to I should need to do `*(argv[0])`. What is happening here? Is C doing some kind of magic here?

```
+------+------+------+---+---+----+
| h    | e    | l    | l | o | \0 |
+------+------+------+---+---+----+
  ^---- name[0] = h

+------+------+------+
| 0xA7 | 0xCE | 0xC4 |
+------+------+------+
   ^---- argv[0] = should be 0XA7 (the value of `argv[0]`,
                   not the value it points to
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char name[] = "hello";

    printf("%c \n", name[0]); // expected h
    printf("%s \n", argv[0]); // expected 0xA7 (but got ./a.out instead)
}
```

```
$ gcc main.c
$ ./a.out arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: What do you think `%s` means to `printf`?

Comment: `argv[0]` is a `char*` - which points to a null-terminated byte string. Which is exactly what you are printing with `%s`. Why would you ever expect the `%s` specifier to print an address instead of a string?

Comment: In POSIX systems, `argv[0]` is the name of the _program_. Passed args start at `argv[1]`. Try: `for (int idx = 0;  idx < argc;  ++idx) printf("%d: %s\n",idx,argv[idx]);`

Comment: If you want the address of a string you want `%p` not `%s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My reasoning is that if I wanted to access the actual content of the memory address that argv[0] points to I should need to do *(argv[0]). What is happening here?

`printf` is doing the dereferencing. When passed `"%s"` and a pointer (address), `printf` doesn't print the address. It prints what's at the address. Specifically, it prints `ptr[0]`, `ptr[1]`, `ptr[2]` etc until a zero is encountered.

(Keep in mind that `ptr[i]` is identical to `*(ptr+i)`. I'm going to use the former since it's cleaner.)

---

Let's start with a simpler example.

```c
char *name = "hello";
printf( "%s", name );
```

```
name
+-------------------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| [Some address 1] -------->| 'h' | 'e' | 'l' | 'l' | 'o' |  0  |
+-------------------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Passing `"%s", name` passes the address of an array containing `%s␀` and the address contained by `name` ("[Some address 1]"). The latter is the address of an array containing `hello␀`.

This tells `printf` to print `name[0]` (`h`), `name[1]` (`e`), `name[2]` (`l`), etc until a zero is encountered.

---

Now let's look at your case.

```
argv
+-------------------+       +-------------------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| [Some address 2] -------->| [Some address 3] -------->| '.' | '/' | 'a' | '.' | 'o' | 'u' | 't' |  0  |
+-------------------+       +-------------------+        -----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
                            | [Some address 4] -------->| 'a' | 'r' | 'g' | '1' |  0  |
                            +-------------------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
                            | [Some address 5] -------->| 'a' | 'r' | 'g' | '2' |  0  |
                            +-------------------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
                            | [Some address 6] -------->| 'a' | 'r' | 'g' | '3' |  0  |
                            +-------------------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
                            | NULL              |
                            +-------------------+
```

or just

```
argv[0]
+-------------------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| [Some address 3] -------->| '.' | '/' | 'a' | '.' | 'o' | 'u' | 't' |  0  |
+-------------------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Passing `"%s", argv[0]` passes the address of an array containing `%s␀` and the address contained by `argv[0]` ("[Some address 3]"). The latter is the address of an array containing `./a.out␀`.

This tells `printf` to print `argv[0][0]` (`.`), `argv[0][1]` (`/`), `argv[0][2]` (`.`), etc until a zero is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

For an array declared like:

```
char name[] = "hello";
```

the expression `name[0]` has the type `char` and by using the conversion specifier `c` in the call of printf:

```
printf("%c \n", name[0]);
```

the first element of the array is outputted as a character.

This declaration of an array:

```
char * argv[]
```

that is used as a parameter declaration is adjusted by the compiler to the declaration:

```
char **argv
```

and the expression `argv[0]` has type `char *`.

The conversion specifier `s` is designed to output strings pointed to by corresponding arguments like this:

```
printf("%s \n", argv[0]);
```

`argv[0]` points to a string that contains the name of the program that runs.

If you want to output the expression as an address you need to write:

```
printf("%p \n", ( void * )argv[0]);
```

To make it more clear consider this statement:

```
printf( "%s\n", "Hello" );
```

Its output I think you are expecting is:

```
Hello
```

The string literal has the type `char[6]`. But using as an expression in the call of printf it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element of the type `char *`.

So the second argument of the call of printf has the type `char *` the same way as in the call:

```
printf("%s \n", argv[0]);
```

where the second expression also has the type `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

`%s` tells `printf` “Load characters from the address you are passed and print the characters from there until you find a null character.”

With `%s`, `printf` does not print or format the address it is passed. It uses the address to access memory.